# How to mitigate the lack of suspend-to-ram when idle powerdraw is too high

Tags: power-management, acpi, powertop

My Supermicro [X11-SRM-F](https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/motherboard/X11SRM-F) lacks support for suspend-to-ram, as can be seen from the kernel reporting: `ACPI: (supports S0 S4 S5)` and has been confirmed by Supermicro support.

I used a [kill-a-watt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_A_Watt) meter to check the idle power usage of the machine, and that sits at **44 Watts**.

When, idle, the [Xeon W2140B](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/xeon_w/w-2140b) with a baseclock of 3.2GHz has all cores running at 1.2GHz, which is the minimum as reported by `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq` contents.

I'm puzzled where this power-draw comes from, when my system is idle.

The [powertop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerTOP) tool shows that the CPU is in C6 for 99.7% of the time, and gives a **3 Watts** estimate for CPU+RAM when my desktop is idle:

```
System baseline power is estimated at 2.90 W

Power est.    Usage     Device name
  1.81 W      3.4%        DRAM
  1.10 W      3.4%        CPU misc
```

Add to that the power-draw from the GTX1650 GPU, which [nvtop](https://github.com/Syllo/nvtop) reports as using **6 Watts** on an idle desktop.

The system also has 2 NVMe drives, which do not get warm, so would not account for the missing 35 Watts.

Is that all due to the inefficiency of the PSU? The [550W PSU](https://antec.com/product/power/eag-pro550.php) is 80 PLUS GOLD certified.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are other loads you have not accounted for yet, like fans, motherboard stuff, ... But yes, there will be some minimal power consumption for the power supply itself. You need to also watch the power factor, as in my experience it is poor for minimal load and only gets close to 1 for maximum processor package power. Overall, good switching power supplies should be into the 90% area for efficiency, but do require minimal load to work properly (at least they did years ago, when I was more knowledgeable about them).

For my main test computer, idling at 1.3 watts processor package power, the mains are at 35.7 watts, with power factor at about 0.85. For low powers my mains ~= 34 + processor package power. At 87 watts processor package power, the mains draw about 128 watts, or another 41 watts. So, 5.3 watts unaccounted for. Some of that will be extra memory power, but lets us call that 0. So the 5.3 extra waste watts cost of the additional 85.7 processor watts suggests an efficiency of 94%, which is good.